# Javascript Like Modal Window for WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-controls, modal-dialog

Does anybody know a good Modal Window control sort of like the ones used in Javascript but available for WinForms (C#) with the transparent background and all.

Example in Javascript
http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/

Something like

```
ModalCoolForm f = new ModalCoolForm();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a custom Form that'll do what you want... alter to your taste:

```
public partial class ModalLoadingUI : Form
{
    #region Constants
    private readonly Color BackgroundFadeColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ModalLoadingUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the main form that will be used as a background canvas for the loading form.
    /// </summary>
    public Form BackgroundForm { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the text to displayed as the progress text.
    /// </summary>
    public string Title
    { 
        get
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the value of the progress bar.
    /// </summary>
    public int? Progress
    {
        get
        {
            if (progressBar1.Style == ProgressBarStyle.Marquee)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return progressBar1.Value;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
                progressBar1.Value = 100;

                label2.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
                progressBar1.Value = value.Value;

                label2.Text = string.Format("{0}%", value);
                label2.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets a value to indicate if the background form should be faded out.
    /// </summary>
    public bool UseFadedBackground { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets a value to indicate if the splash box is to be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public bool UseSplashBox
    {
        get
        {
            return picShadow.Visible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                picShadow.Visible = true;
                panel1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                picShadow.Visible = false;
                panel1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Base Events
    private void ModalLoadingUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BackgroundForm != null)
        {
            this.Location = this.BackgroundForm.Location;
        }
    }

    private void ModalLoadingUI_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible == true)
        {
            if (this.BackgroundForm != null)
            {
                this.Location = this.BackgroundForm.Location;
            }
        }

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == true)
        {
            this.TopMost = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
    }

    private void ModalLoadingUI_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Paints the background form as the background of this form, if one is defined.
    /// </summary>
    public void CaptureBackgroundForm()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(CaptureBackgroundForm));
            return;
        }

        if (this.BackgroundForm == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        try
        {
            // COPY BACKGROUND
            int x = this.BackgroundForm.Left;
            int y = this.BackgroundForm.Top;
            var size = this.BackgroundForm.Size;

            g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            // FADE IF DESIRED
            if (this.UseFadedBackground == true)
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);

                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackgroundFadeColor), rect);
            }

            // PAINT SPLASH BOX SHADOW IF DESIRED
            if(this.UseSplashBox == true)
            {
                PaintPanelShadow(g);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
        }

        this.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenshot;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Paints a shadow around the panel, if one is defined.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to paint into</param>
    private void PaintPanelShadow(Graphics g)
    {
        var shadowImage = picShadow.Image;

        var x = panel1.Left + (panel1.Width / 2) - (shadowImage.Width / 2);
        var y = panel1.Top + (panel1.Height / 2) - (shadowImage.Height / 2);

        g.DrawImage(shadowImage, x, y, shadowImage.Width, shadowImage.Height);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can't get this working for love nor money. The captured bittmap is just plain black. I don't think this answer really has sufficient detail.

Comment: @ chipples: You need to create the designer file and extrapolate out what tools to add from the toolbox. The solution is generic enough, but it will not function without some effort.

Comment: Typically, you would add this to an existing form. The crucial element to observe is "panel1" which should be added to your form and all the other elements should be added to that.

Comment: I suggest that you start by just implementing only the "Progress" method in the context of your partial form class.