# disable "Close" button when another dialog is on top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I currently have a problem with forms here.

Whenever some process is ongoing, I have a progress dialog that should popup, but when I click the "X" button of the window/form behind my progress dialog, it will be dismissed and the ongoing operation is cancelled.

How can I prevent that from happening? Should I have to disable my whole form behind my progress bar? and how can I do it?

p.s.
I have tried [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/216690/disable-close-button) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atosah/archive/2007/05/18/disable-close-x-button-in-winforms-using-c.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms) but NONE of them seems to work in my application. T__T

Comment: When showing the progress bar, you should prevent user from clicking any thing in the behind form.

Comment: yes. that's it. that's exactly what I wanted to happen..and how can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the form using [`Form.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) instead of `Form.Show()`.  That will disable the background form (actually any other form in the process) until the form you are showing closes.  As an added benefit you can have the form return a value (e.g. Cancel, OK, Yes, No, etc.) in case any action needs to be taken as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually the answer you might be expecting, but you could handle the `Form.FormClosing` event, setting `e.Cancel = True`

This won't disable the Close button, but will make your form remain open in this case.

See more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Comonly used in multi-threaded applications (i.e. download managers).

Answer (score 0):

You should show the progress bar as modal dialog, please check whether this answer work for you [javasript like model window on winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698895/javascript-like-modal-window-for-winforms/3640750#3640750)

HTH.