# Graphics.CopyFromScreen just my app window

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using copyfromscreen to show a modal please wait message.
It works great but i find it failing when I'm doing alt tab to the app or I'm looking to another app and come back to my application.

Original post I got the idea from:
[Javascript Like Modal Window for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698895/javascript-like-modal-window-for-winforms/3640750#3640750)

I was curious if there is a function that would let me get screen capture of my app only even when its hidden in the background.

Comment: it your app fires it from a mouse or button click, how would your app get the click when it is in the background?

Comment: `Control.DrawToBitmap`... but this seems like a bad idea for a multitasking operating system. Consider using either `MessageBox` or creating your own custom form that you display using its `ShowDialog` member function. It is automatically modal.

Comment: the idea is not to halt the main screen, so it continues to show the form just dont allow user to control it. I am using MDI parent and forms including the please wait shows in there. the background processes update and notify the please wait message with count and progress bar info. works really well except the screen shot isn't current.

Comment: actually the drawtobitmap worked. I am gonna do some testing on it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Control.DrawToBitmap Cody Gray suggestion actually works. Just grab the forms bitmap instead of doing full screen grab.